# How to set hardware clock to correct time?

Tags: time

How can I set the hardware clock to my correct local time?

hwclock shows:

[image]

instead of 06:42 it should be 18:42

My timezone is Europe/Berlin

How can I fix this?

Comment: 6:42 **PM** is 18:42 Hours! The clock is showing the correct time.

Comment: on another ubuntu server I get 18:42 using the same command.

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation about the hardware clock [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/hwclock-examples/?utm_source=tuicool) whcih you might find useful

Simply the commands are these to write the system time to hardware time:

```
# sudo hwclock -w [or --systohc]
```

check what effect it had:

```
# hwclock
Sat 10 Aug 2013 08:16:27 AM PDT  -0.625382 seconds

# date
Sat Aug 10 08:16:28 PDT 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change a locale called `LC_TIME`

This will show what you use now:

```
$ env | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
```

It probably is set differently (and to one where they use 12-hour format)sudo

This would be German:

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8
```